# Installing libc6 on Google Colab

Tags: error-handling, google-colaboratory, blender, glibc, libc

Hello i wanted to run Blender K-Cycles on Google Colab but got the following error message

```
lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found
lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found
```

Can i somewhow install libc6 on Colab?

I´m glad for every answer!

Answer (score 1):

> Can i somewhow install libc6 on Colab?

The `libc.so.6` is part of the `libc6` (GLIBC) package and *is already installed*.

Your problem is that the installed GLIBC is too old for the binary you are trying to run.

Usually the solution is to find (or build from source) a release of the binary you want to run built *for* the OS you are trying to run it on, rather than update the OS to suite the binary.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! Unfortunately I'm not really familiar with Python. To change the application (K-Cycles) I had no idea what to do there either. The normal Blender version runs on Google Colab without any problems. Isn't there an easy way to update the libc6 (GLIBC) package?

Comment: @Tim "Isn't there an easy way to update the libc6 (GLIBC) package?" -- no. That package is considered to be part of the OS, and most Linux distributions do not allow you to update it without updating the _entire OS_.

Comment: Oh ok  Hmm to bad..